# 25LC080 EEPROM communication

Tags: embedded

Have anyone used the 25LC080 EEPROM in their project, especially with the LPC1788 MCU. I have tried various way but still have no luck . What I find suspicous is the SI & SO lines are  high when I first power up. Is this normal ?

Thanks all

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com), I think the probability of getting an answer there is higher.

Comment: The statement `tried various way` doesn't tell us to much *what* you did. The `25LC080` is a SPI device. I would give the CMIS library a chance to to initialize the SPI interface and to communicate with the EEPROM.

Comment: Is SO *driven* high, or merely *floating* there?  If you configure the corresponding MCU pin with a pulldown, or ground it through a 10K resistor, does it go low?

Answer (score 0):

An operating with this device is pretty common and you just need to follow the documentation.

**Read Sequence**

The device is selected by pulling `CS` low. The 8-bit `READ` instruction is transmitted to the 25XX080 followed by the 16-bit address, with the six MSBs of the address being "don’t care" bits. After the correct `READ` instruction and address are sent, the data stored in the memory at the selected address is shifted out on the `SO` pin. The data stored in the memory at the next address can be read sequentially by continuing to provide clock pulses. The internal address pointer is automatically incremented to the next higher address after each byte of data is shifted out. When the highest address is reached (03FFh), the address counter rolls over to address 0000h allowing the read cycle to be continued indefinitely. The read operation is terminated by raising the `CS` pin.

And the `READ` command and others are as follows:

[image]

Further reading you can find on Microchip site by this [link](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21230D.pdf).

Comment: Thanks all for all the suggestion .. I finally figure it out .. I have to keep the clock going (by sending 0) in order to receive data back

Comment: @ThuanTran oh yes, indeed